# In Eclipse, my imports are same in the line of code ? How to correct it?

Tags: eclipse

What i am getting

```
java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","admin","admin")
```

but i want like this

```
imports java.sql.Connection;
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","admin","admin")
```

How to get this in eclipse ?

Comment: It is `import` not `imports` and it must be at the top of source file just after the `package` statement. Just type `Connection` and use 'Source > Add Import` to find the import or use Ctrl+Space to get a completion suggestion.

Comment: if i use source or ctrl + space also this specific imports alone is in same line other import are top of the code.. connections and @Test import's in java and testng, are in the same line of code. I don't know why ??

Comment: Do you have an import for another `Connection` class? Only one class with a given name can be imported, any others with the same name have to use the full name like this.

Comment: Connection is default present java.sql.Connection and only one class